# Precision issues between Excel + VBA with currency formats

Tags: excel, vba, precision

I have a user defined function (UDF) which takes two inputs.  Both inputs have been declared as type `Double`.  However, while the input has a large number of decimal places, once passed to the UDF, the number of decimal places gets truncated.

Curiously, I cannot seem to reproduce this behaviour in a clean workbook (ie, I wonder if there is something going on with this particular workbook...).

The (simplied) UDF is below.

```
Function Wage(HourlyWage As Double, HoursWorked As Double) As Double

    Wage = HourlyWage

End Function
```

as well as a screenshot of what is happening.

[image]

The formula bar shows the UDF call.  It is taking columns C and D as inputs.  HourlyWage is 25.30364372+ in column C, but once passed to the UDF Wage, the HourlyWage is truncated to 25.30360000 despite being declared as type `Double`.

I understand general points about floating point precision, but this surely applies equally to the input in column C as it does to the UDF (indeed, column C is in actual fact the output of another UDF which has been declared as type `Double`).

[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)

[Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Additional information about the EXCEL workbook.

- I am using Windows 7 Professional and Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus 64-bit version.
- The workbook is an .xlsb format.  I have also saved as .xlsm and it does not fix the issue.
- I cannot reproduce in a clean workbook.
- The workbook contains a large number of interrelated user defined functions (maybe 40)
- The workbook contains 11 sheets.  5 of these are datasheets with a number of parameters, but I wouldn't have said large in the grand scheme of things (around 100 rows and 30 columns).  3 sheets have a largeish number of UDF and calculations (again, 100 rows by maybe 40-50 columns)
- I wouldn't have said the workbook is large.  It is 369Kb (.xlsb) and 525KB (.xlsm)
- However, the workbook is taking an unexpectedly long time to recalculated when input parameters are changed (say around 10 seconds which I find surprising as it doesn't seem a lot of calculations in the grand scheme of things)

Any ideas on how to fix this?  The loss of precision is causing me issues...

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I get `25.30364372` as output using your UDF code.

Comment: Do you have event-triggered macros in your workbook that are doing some rounding on column E?

Comment: Hi Ron.  No, I do not.

Comment: @brb What is the result of `Debug.Print [C6], [E6]` just to ensure there is no odd number format.

Comment: Highlight the numbers in column D and copy. Highlight the numbers in column F and Paste Format.  What happens?

Comment: If your calculation involves any VBA variables with data type Currency then those can only have a maximum of 4 digits to the right of the decimal point - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type) That would seem to match the behaviour that you are seeing

Comment: Can you put a break in the UDF (on the `Exit Sub` line) and see what the value of `Wage` is?  Is it simply a matter of formatting on the cell?

Comment: Thank you all help, particularly @barrowc - it is an issue with the currency format.  I will write up the answer to help others, but if you wanted to write the answer or repaste mine, I will accept your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on comments from barrowc and Peh above.  Thank you both for your help.

Currency data types have a maximum of 4 decimal points (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type).

Column C has been formatted with a custom currency format.  When fed to the VBA UDF function, decimal points beyond the 4th decimal place are truncated despite the variable being declared as type `Double` inside the UDF.

Changing the number format solves the problem as per screenshot below.

[image]

This can be verified using Debug.Print

```
Sub brb()
    Debug.Print [C6], [E6]
    Debug.Print [C8], [E8]
End Sub
```

[image]